# Jquery function closing div on append by itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have the following function:

```
function displayResults(Items) {
                $("#result").text("");
                $("#result").append('<div class="car-offers">');
                $("#result").append('<div class="purple"></div>');
                $("#result").append('<img src="images/caroffer.jpg" alt="" title="" width="213" height="117" />');
                $("#result").append('<h3>titleeee</h3>'); // ' + Items[i].Title + '
                $("#result").append('<span>Year: 2003</span>');
                $("#result").append('<span>Milage: 172,000 Km</span>');
                $("#result").append('<span class="price">53,000 QR</span>');
                $("#result").append('<a href="">Link</a>');
                $("#result").append('</div>');

                $("#result").append('<div class="car-offers">');
                $("#result").append('<div class="purple"></div>');
                $("#result").append('<img src="images/caroffer.jpg" alt="" title="" width="213" height="117" />');
                $("#result").append('<h3>titlee22</h3>'); // ' + Items[i].Title + '
                $("#result").append('<span>Year: 2003</span>');
                $("#result").append('<span>Milage: 172,000 Km</span>');
                $("#result").append('<span class="price">53,000 QR</span>');
                $("#result").append('<a href="">Link</a>');
                $("#result").append('</div>');
        }
```

my problem is that at run-time the html is being displayed like: `<div class="car-offers"></div>` so all the page is being messed up

Comment: why not you make it a single string and then append that string

Comment: apart from question: Using js temlating engine like Handlebars would be much more readable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot append incomplete fragments of HTML with [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/). Unlike `document.write`, jQuery's `.append()` method parses the passed string into elements before appending them to the DOM.

So when you do:

```
$("#result").append('<div class="car-offers">');
```

jQuery parses the given string into a `div` element and assigns the `car-offers` value to its `className` property, then appends the newly created element to the `#result` element.

Appending the whole HTML string in a single operation will fix that, so jQuery knows how to parse the given string correctly.

---

Personally, I wouldn't suggest putting that much HTML inside of a JS file. You can consider putting that inside of a `div` with `display:none` then simply call `.show()` on it. Or have it initially in the page, [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) it storing in a variable and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) it back when necessary.

Answer (score 9):

You can use a array with [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to solve this

```
function displayResults(Items) {
    $("#result").text("");
    var array = [];
    array.push('<div class="car-offers">');
    array.push('<div class="purple"></div>');
    array
            .push('<img src="images/caroffer.jpg" alt="" title="" width="213" height="117" />');
    array.push('<h3>titleeee</h3>'); // ' + Items[i].Title + '
    array.push('<span>Year: 2003</span>');
    array.push('<span>Milage: 172,000 Km</span>');
    array.push('<span class="price">53,000 QR</span>');
    array.push('<a href="">Link</a>');
    array.push('</div>');

    array.push('<div class="car-offers">');
    array.push('<div class="purple"></div>');
    array
            .push('<img src="images/caroffer.jpg" alt="" title="" width="213" height="117" />');
    array.push('<h3>titlee22</h3>'); // ' + Items[i].Title + '
    array.push('<span>Year: 2003</span>');
    array.push('<span>Milage: 172,000 Km</span>');
    array.push('<span class="price">53,000 QR</span>');
    array.push('<a href="">Link</a>');
    array.push('</div>');
    $("#result").text(array.join(''));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue I've just come across too. An option is to create the div containers first in a loop then populate them after as you require:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){

    $(el).append('<li class="scene-block"></li>'); // create container li tags

    //fill empty li tags with content
    for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        $(el).find('li').last().append('<div class="select-a-scene-bg"></div>');
    }

}
```